# String length limit in MSVC during compile?

Tags: c++, gcc, string-length

I am converting C++ codes from Linux to windows (using Visual Studio 2013). But MSVC has length limit on string (around 2048 bytes?), the GCC doesn't instead. My problem is that, there is a config file containing several huge string, it works well under GCC. But MSVC reports compile error as

> error C2026: string too big, trailing characters truncated.

The string is quite simple, `CONFIGSTRING` is huge.

```
const std::string CONFIGSTRING="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Any solution for this problem? Can I separately compile the config file to object file using GCC under windows and link it to other files? If possible, anyone can briefly show me how to do it?

Comment: What kind of string are you talking about? `std::string`? Can you post a line of code that represents the problem you're attempting to solve?

Comment: [OP's already noticed this, but it does suggest a solution.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx08afx2.aspx)

Comment: [There is also this about the error explaining how to fix it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dddywwsc.aspx)

Comment: @NathanOliver already did as suggested (\), but the example is "char sz[] =", my case is "string CONFIGSTRING="xxxxxxxx" ". Not sure if (\) works for string.

Comment: It will work. It's not the `const std::string` the compiler is complaining about, it's the very large string literal you're using to construct it.

Comment: Explaining what @RobK said, the C++ `std::string` type has no with strings this long, but the VS C++ compiler is barfing at encountering the string in the source file, and the same would likely happen if you tried to have a literal character array that long in your source code, even if you didn't operate with or on that array.

Answer (score 3):

According to the MSDN docs, this should work:

```
const std::string str =
  "xxxx" // Max 2048 bytes
  "xxxx" // Max 2048 bytes
         // ... and so on (up to 65535 bytes)
  ;
```

If this is still not sufficient, then do:

```
std::string str;
str = "part1";
str += "part2";
str += "part3"; // And so on.
```

---

> Can I separately compile the config file to object file using GCC under windows and link it to other files?

No, they are using different C++ standard libraries.

Comment: I can confirm that the first method works, I cut up my string into 2000 byte segments to make a 30,000 byte total.