# Increase string literal length limit

Tags: c++, string, gcc, visual-c++, compilation

I have a lot of string literals that are bigger than 65535 bytes. I'm not allowed to save these strings to seperate files, how can I workaround with the string limit?

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488682/7821462
>
> - MSVC: 2048
> - GCC: No Limit (up to 100,000 characters), but gives warning after 510 characters:
>
>   ```
>   String literal of length 100000 exceeds maximum length 509 that
>   C90 compilers are required to support
>   ```

Comment: One option is to split strings to different variables inside single file and then use array of pointers to these variables. It makes your life harder but that's the nature

Comment: For which compiler? gcc, MSVC or both?

Comment: *Why* can't you use files (or some other database) to store the texts? What requirement do you have that doesn't allow that?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I need to make strings work with MSVC first, then gcc later.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The requirement is I need to ship everything in one single executable file.

Comment: Answer for MSVC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460913/string-length-limit-in-msvc-during-compile

Comment: @Rakete1111 Concatenating strings only works when it's smaller than 65535 bytes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx08afx2.aspx

Comment: Of interest, what do you do with these large strings?

Comment: Write some custom class using a `std::vector<char>` that allows concatenating string literals beyond the limit?

Comment: Write some code to auto-gen a header of string fragments and some code to join it back together. Grind your input through your tool and then use your auto-gen'ed code at run time.

Comment: If this isn't overkill, compress and base 64 encode the strings

Answer (score 4):

These large strings seem more like resources than code, and I would use the resource section of a windows binary (FindResource/LoadResource) and the answer to the [SO: embedding resources into linux executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479691/is-there-any-standard-way-of-embedding-resources-into-linux-executable-image) to insert the same data into linux.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the text string into multiple strings.  Following code worked on Visual Studio 2017:

```
const char* p1 = "1234567890...";  // Very long (length > 65000)
const char* p2 = "abcdefghij...";  // Very long (length > 65000)
string s = p1;
s += p2;
cout << s.size() << endl;
```

You have to write the text string in multiple lines like:

```
const char* p = "This is a "
    "very long string...";
```

Actually the maximum limit in Visual C++ is 65535.  Here is the compiler error message:

*fatal error C1091: compiler limit: string exceeds 65535 bytes in length*

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81k8cwsz.aspx

> The maximum size for an array is defined by size_t. Defined in the header file STDDEF.H, size_t is an unsigned int with the range 0x00000000 to 0x7CFFFFFF.

Answer (score -3):

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/maximum-string-length) says that using concatenation (i.e., writing `"a" "b" "c"` instead of `"abc"`) allows you to increase the limit to around 64 KiB bytes.  But this is not sufficient for your use case.

If not, you can perhaps save the string separately, convert it to a byte array initializer using `xxd -i` (`xxd comes with [vim](http://www.vim.org/)), and`#include` that (but you'll have to add the null terminator manually).

Comment: I've written that the string literals are bigger than 65535 bytes, I'll take a look at the array initializer technique.